# Show HTML in Console.Log() instead of jQuery selection Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, developer-tools

I'm to output the real html in  Chrome developer console for easier debugging.
So I thought of making a chrome extension, which is [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/consolelog-output-real-ht/jnfjicjapkamepnbiplhcjhcjccmegna).

I copied the real console.log() to console.nativeLog(); and I added my own custom function to console.log();

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="myDiv">
        <input type="text" id="inp1" title="title1" />
        <input type="text" id="inp2" title="title2" />
        <input type="text" id="inp3" title="title3" />
        <input type="text" id="inp4"  />
        <input type="text" id="test" value="">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Add" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.nativeLog = console.log;
    var arr= new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
        arr[i] = i+','+i;
    }
    var fav = JSON.parse('[{"href":"/EMS-ILS/Modules/Supplier_Profile/Supplier_Profile.aspx?ModID=6&WebPageID=38","text":"Supplier Profile"},{"href":"/EMS-ILS/Modules/Customer_Profile/Customer_Profile.aspx?ModID=6&WebPageID=57","text":"Customer Profile"},{"href":"/EMS-ILS/Modules/Costing_Profile/Costing_Profile.aspx?ModID=6&WebPageID=50","text":"Costing Profile"}]')
        console.log = function (val){
            if(typeof(val)=='string'){
                console.nativeLog(val);
                return;
            }
            try{
                for(var x=0;x<arguments.length;x++){
                    var arr = arguments[x];
                    try{
                        if(!arr.length)
                            console.nativeLog(arr);
                        else {
                            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                                console.nativeLog(arr[i]);
                        }
                    }catch(err1){
                        console.nativeLog(arr);
                    }
                }
            }   
            catch(err2){
                console.nativeLog(val);
            }
        }           
        $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log('-------------');
            console.log($('input'));
            console.log('-------------');
            console.log($('#inp1'));
            console.log('-------------');
            console.log($('#badId'));
            console.log('-------------');   
                            console.log($('input'), $('#bad'), $('input:text'),  fav, 0, arr)


        });
    </script>
```

Everything works fine, but the last one. If the jquery object contains no results, it will still print the context jquery object.

This is the output in console.

[image]

How can prevent that? Any Ideas. Thanks.

Comment: what would you like the output to be? a blank line or no output at all?

Comment: May be an empty array []

Comment: my implementation below just yields a blank line. This makes the logic simpler, but I can amend it to print an empty array.

Comment: okay, I updated my implementation to print [] when the jquery object is empty. you can change it to whatever works best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/KYvDX/3/. This will print each argument on a separate line and print [] if the jQuery object is empty:

```
console.nativeLog = console.log;
console.log = function(val) {
    var x = 0;
    for (x; x < arguments.length; x++) {
        var item = arguments[x];
        // check if we are dealing with jQuery object
        if (item instanceof jQuery) {
            // jQuery objects with length property are
            // the only ones we want to print
            if (item.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                    console.nativeLog(item[i]);
                }
            } else {
                console.nativeLog('[]');
            }
        } else {
            console.nativeLog(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a more accurate replication of the actual console.log behavior for printing multiple arguments eg. `console.log('a', 'b', 2, [])` on one line: http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/KYvDX/4/

```
console.nativeLog = console.log;
console.log = function() {
    var x = 0;
    var output = [];
    for (x; x < arguments.length; x++) {
        item = arguments[x];
        if (item instanceof jQuery) {
            if (item.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                    output.push(item[i]);
                }
            } else {
                output.push('[]');
            }
        } else {
            output.push(item);
        }
    }
    console.nativeLog.apply(this, output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried your code. It printing all. But the problem is it will print all together making it quite difficult to read. I'll update my question

Comment: the first version doesn't print all together: http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/KYvDX/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
    console.log($('#badId')[0] != undefined ? $('#badId') : 'do not exist');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bkPRg/2/

Comment: I suppose that it would be better if($('#badId').length > 0)

Comment: I want to check this inside the console.log function :(

Comment: He overrode the console.log implementation. He wants the fix inside his implementation. Look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.html()
```

or

```
.text()
```

Also you might check this one for the `jquery .length` property:

```
var arr = arguments[x];
                    try{
                        if(!arr.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a judgement before print the jQuery object

```
console.log = function (val){
    if(typeof(val)=='string'){
        console.nativeLog(val);
        return;
    }
    else if(val instanceof jQuery && val.length==0)
    {
        console.nativeLog("A jQuery object with no html element");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: This will work for the jQuery object, but it will break the native console.log implementation for other types. For example, arrays of length 0 will log as "A jquery object..."

Comment: @teddybeard You're right. Should judge it's a jquery object first. My answer is updated.